# Internal Bug Tracker: No way to remove it

Tags: kiwi-tcms

We are using external bug tracker - Redmine.

How do I remove the internal bug tracker?

[example of internal bug tracking are added to menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXEK0.png)

Answer (score 1):

See the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting from https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html which contains this comment:

```
# if you wish to disable Kiwi TCMS bug tracker
# comment out the next line
'tcms.bugs',
```

What happens when you do what it says ?